# Jquery recursive focus on textbox not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog, focus

I'm having trouble with jquery focus.

So here's what I want to accomplish:

To solve ie placeholder issue, I want to focus to an element and then blur it to make the placeholder appear. I'm currently using it on a modal form.

It works fine on the first load of the modal form, but closing the form and opening it again seems not to work.

So far I've narrowed down the issue to focus not being triggered by $("#element").focus() more than once.

here is a fiddle to illustrate the issue

http://jsfiddle.net/Ere2N/1/

JS:

```
var i = 5;

while(i>0){
    focusMe();
    i--;
}

function focusMe(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#text1').focus().queue(function(){
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#text2').focus().queue(function(){
                setTimeout(function(){$('#text1').focus();},100);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#text2').focus();
                }, 300);
            })
        }, 300);
        });                
    },100);
}

$("#text1").focus(function(){
    $("#count1").html(($("#count1").html()*1) + 1);
});

$("#text2").focus(function(){
    $("#count2").html(($("#count2").html()*1) + 1);
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="text1" />
<input type="text" id="text2" />
<input type="text" id="text3" />

<div id="count1">0</div>
<div id="count2">0</div>
```

it behaving funny..

1st execution of the function is good.

However 2nd to last execution only executes the first #text1 focus, thus producing the resulting statistics of 6:2.

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 0):

.focus only run code that you wrote on focus event 
use "trigger" or use getElementById().focus

Comment: Hi @saman Thanks for the quick response. I've already tried the trigger before, but the result is the same. Only the 1st focus us executed on the second loop.

Comment: update: tried replacing .focus with getElementById().focus. And its not working.